# When is $0=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n\right) \ ?$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

I have a very fundamental question related to both basic set theory (and some Probability Theory)

> Let $A_n$ be a sequence of events. Suppose that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=0$$
>
> When can we write$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n\right) \ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $B_N:=\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n$. The sequence $\left(B_N\right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing. Therefore, we have 
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}   \Pr\left(B_N\right)=\Pr\left(\bigcap_{N\geqslant 1}B_N\right).$$
We thus have 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\Pr\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n\right) =0$$
if and only if $  \Pr\left(\bigcap_{N\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n\right)=0$. In other words, the probability that infinitely many $A_n$'s are realized should be zero. Now the keyword is the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: You mean $A_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0\ \ ?$

Comment: How do you know that $B_N$ is non-increasing?It seems to me that it is trivially non-decreasing, but non-increasing seems less obvious to me

Comment: Isn't it this? $$\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n\supseteq \bigcup_{n\geqslant N+1}A_n$$